# Generic advice on reducing GC time in GHC

Tags: optimization, haskell, garbage-collection, ghc

Are there any generic rules to follow in order to discover the cause when a GHC-compiled program spends to much time doing garbage collection? And what would be generally considered too much? For example, in general, is 60% productivity acceptable or is it an indication that something is likely wrong with the code?

Comment: To reduce GC you can first use GHC's profiling to track which code is allocating the most.

Comment: Allocate less, and you'll get less GC.  I generally think 25% GC is acceptable, higher than that and I start looking for ways to reduce allocation.

Comment: Often, running the program with "+RTS -H" helps a lot. Also, build with -O2.

Comment: @ChrisKuklewicz: Unfortunately compiling with profiling totally changes the performance of the program: with no profiling, I get a productivity of 60%, with profiling on, 2.4%. No I can't really trust the output of the profiler in this case.

Comment: You can get a `-hT` profile with a non-profiling build (needs `-rtsopts` of course, but no `-prof`). That might point you to the problematic parts.

Comment: @Grzegorz: is that change just from compiling with `-profiling`, or are you also using `-auto` or `-auto-all`?  If it's one of the `-auto` flags, you can manually set cost centers with the `SCC` pragma.  That sometimes produces code closer to the production version.

Comment: @JohnL: Yes I was using `-auto-all`. I'll try the manual way then, thanks. Although I'm suspecting that the profiler is disabling fusion in the Data.Vector module, and this causes most of the difference...

Comment: @Grzegorz: if the `vector` package was installed with `-auto-all` also, you may need to reinstall it with `-auto`, or no profiling.  That would definitely interfere with fusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a quick and very incomplete list:

1. Test and benchmark. One of haskell's few weaknesses is the difficulty in predicting time and space costs. If you don't have test data you've got nothing.
2. Use better algorithms. This sounds too simple, but optimizing inefficient algorithms is like rapping s**t in gold.
3. Strategically make some data more strict. **Test and Benchmark!** The goal is to store the physically smaller WHNF value rather then the thunk that produces it, thereby cleaning up more garbage in the most efficient first pass. look for complicated functions that produce simple data.
4. Strategically make some data less strict. **Test and Benchmark!** The goal is delay production of a large amount of data until just before it is used and discarded, thereby cleaning up more garbage in the most efficient first pass.  Look for simple functions that produce large complex data.  See also comonads.
5. Strategically make use of arrays and unboxed types, in particular see #2. with regard to the ST monad. **Test and Benchmark!** All of these fit more raw data into smaller more compact memory. There is less garbage to collect.
6. Fiddle with the RTS settings (ghc specific). **Test and Benchmark!** The goal is to "impedence match" the GC with the memory needs of your program.  I get even more lost here then in 1-5 so ask the experts on this one.

Better garbage collection has a fairly simple premise: Create less garbage, collect it sooner, produce fewer memory allocations/deallocations. Any thing you can do that might result in one of these three effects is worth a shot. **Test and Benchmark!**

Comment: +1 for making connection between algorithm optimization, and dressing up fecal matter. Putting lipstick on pig is now getting old, eh :)